# Facebook token invalid but can access api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have a token from facebook (from the graph explorer tool). I am using the PHP sdk. I created a session using the said token and called the FacebookSession::validate() method. It returned TRUE. I uploaded it in a test server and when I run it it says Session has expired. I debugged the token and the expiry should last 2 months.

When I try getting the user info (in the test server) it also works. Even the session info. It only throws a "session has expired" exception when I call the validate() method. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Take note that this only happened after I uploaded it on a live server. The code on my local server and live are the same.

Here is a sample code. The appid and secret are already set by calling the setDefaultApplication() method.

```
<?php

\Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app-id','app-secret');
$s = new \Facebook\FacebookSession('my-access-token');
$u = null;
try {
    $fbr = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($s, 'GET', '/1663246619?fields=id,first_name,last_name,gender,email,birthday,bio');
    $u = $fbr->execute();
    $i = $s->getSessionInfo();
    var_dump($i->getProperty('is_valid'));
    var_dump($s->validate());
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}

var_dump($u->getGraphObject()->asArray());
```

Here is the response

```
bool(true)

string(50) "Session has expired, or is not valid for this app."

array(11) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(10) "1663246619"
  ["email"]=>
  string(22) "my-email@email.com"
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(12) "Kapitanluffy"
  ["gender"]=>
  string(6) "female"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(6) "Pirata"
  ["link"]=>
  string(34) "http://www.facebook.com/1663246619"
  ["locale"]=>
  string(5) "en_US"
  ["name"]=>
  string(19) "Kapitanluffy Pirata"
  ["timezone"]=>
  int(8)
  ["updated_time"]=>
  string(24) "2014-12-06T23:47:48+0000"
  ["verified"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

other notes:

- The access token is for my app
- I am using facebook-php-sdk-v4 version 4.0.3

Comment: are you using the token you took from Graph Explorer in your Application?

Comment: yes. i even revoked the permissions and re approved them

Comment: you cannot use the same token from Graph Explorer as it is tied to that specific application. You will have to generate an access_token from you application itself.

Comment: I meant the access_token I am using is the access token for my application. I changed the "Graph Explorer" application into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your SDK version to the latest stable version `4.0.12`. There have been a whole lot of [bug fixes and security updates](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#40x) since `4.0.3`. One such bug is related to the session info validation that you're having trouble with. That should hopefully fix your issue. :)